# Applying pagination based condition to my CSS

Tags: html, css, pagination, conditional-statements

I'm trying to set up a pagination based condition to affect my CSS. 
The logic behind the condition is this:
If pagination is equaled to 1, apply CSS "x" 
Else, apply CSS "y"

In other words, I want a specific CSS code to apply on the first page of any gallery in my website, and a different one to all other pages (bigger than or equal to 2)

I'm having trouble forming this pagination condition and applying it.

Thanks for the help!

```
<!--page 1 css-->
    .theiaPostSlider_nav ._prev
 {
    display: none;
}
.theiaPostSlider_nav ._next {
    margin: 0 0px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-weight: 700;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 1px;
    line-height: 1px;
    height: 42px;
    padding: 0 0px;
}

<!--page 2 and higer css-->
.theiaPostSlider_nav ._prev, .theiaPostSlider_nav ._next {
    margin: 0 0px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-weight: 700;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 1px;
    line-height: 1px;
    height: 42px;
    padding: 0 0px;
}
```

Comment: you can use javascript to check your 'pagination' being '1' or '2' and then apply '.css()' value's to '$(this' or any class